# jQuery toggle img with siblings

Tags: jquery, radio-button, siblings

I want to make radio buttons with my images. So i define my div like this:

```
<div id="LabBox">
    <img class="dlike" alt="dlike" src="images/dlike_OFF.png"/>
    <img class="check" alt="check" src="images/check_OFF.png"/>
    <img class="funny" alt="funny" src="images/funny_OFF.png"/>
    <img class="idea" alt="idea" src="images/idea_OFF.png"/>
    <img class="imp" alt="imp" src="images/imp_OFF.png"/>

</div>
```

i would like to toggle in filename. So i use the follow jqueqy code:

```
  $("#LabBox img").click(function () {

var src;    
var srcname = $(this).attr("src");


    // turn on!
if(srcname.toLowerCase().indexOf("off") >= 0){

    //(e.g images/dlike_OFF.png -> images/dlike_ON.png)
src = $(this).attr("src").replace("OFF", "ON");  
    $(this).attr("src", src);   
}   
    // All others turn off! for other words src swap.
  var src2 =$(this).siblings().attr("src").replace("ON", "OFF");
   // All images are the same pic. why?? ---> src="images/dlike_OFF.png"
  console.log(src2);
  $("#LabBox img").attr("src",src2);

    });
```

The problem is when i want to replace to all "brothers" of my selected tag (image).All img change to same img which is the "images/dlike_OFF.png" (first one).
How can i change all my img using siblings()?Or How can i adapt my script to swap all images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#LabBox img").click(function () {
    if (this.src.indexOf('OFF') != -1) {
        this.src = this.src.replace('OFF', 'ON');
    }
    $(this).siblings().attr('src', function(i,src) {
        return src.replace('ON', 'OFF')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/evahoh/3/edit)**</kbd>

```
$("#labBox").on('click','img[src$=OFF]',function () {
  this.src = this.src.replace('OFF', 'ON');
  $(this).siblings().each(function(){
     this.src = this.src.replace('ON', 'OFF');
  });
});
```